# Receiving nullpointer exception for ListView program using custom adapter and orientation?

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, orientation

I'm making an application in which an `ArrayList` is represented by two `ListViews` in both portrait and landscape orientations. To do this, I have been using a single custom adapter of which to inflate my listViews. But I keep receiving a `NullPointer Exception` whenever I instantiate the custom adapter for my `landscape ListView`. Any suggestions?
  Line which throws the exception:

```
listLand.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listPort;
    ListView listLand;
    ArrayList<Flick> flicks;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listLand = findViewById(R.id.listLand);
        listPort = findViewById(R.id.listPort);

        flicks = new ArrayList<>();
        flicks.add(new Flick("Wizard of Oz", "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer", "VARIOUS","1939", "", 98));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Star Wars", "LucasFilm", "George Lucas", "1977","",93));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Psycho","Paramount", "Alfred Hitchcock", "1960", "", 97));
        flicks.add(new Flick("King Kong", "RKO Pictures", "Merian C. Cooper & Ernest B. Schoedsack", "1933", "", 98));
        flicks.add(new Flick("2001: A Space Odyssey", "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer", "Stanley Kubrick", "1968", "", 93));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Citizen Kane", "RKO Pictures", "Orson Welles", "1941", "", 100));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs", "Walt Disney Pictures", "VARIOUS", "1937", "",98));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Casablanca", "Warner Bros.", "Michael Curtiz", "1942", "", 97));
        flicks.add(new Flick("The Godfather", "Paramount", "Francis Ford Coppola", "1972", "", 98));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Jaws", "Universal", "Steven Spielberg", "1975", "", 97));

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_layout, flicks);
        listPort.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        listLand.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flick>
    {
        Context context;
        int resource;
        List<Flick> list;

        public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Flick> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context=context;
            this.resource=resource;
            list=objects;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View adapterView=layoutInflater.inflate(resource,null);


            TextView title = adapterView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView imageView=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Button up=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.upButton);
            Button down=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.downButton);

            title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());

            switch(list.get(position).getStudio())
            {
                case "Warner Bros.":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "Paramount":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "Universal":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "LucasFilm":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "RKO Pictures":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "Walt Disney Pictures":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
            }

            return adapterView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The answer linked to as "duplicate" is not a duplicate, IMO. That question/answer concerns `NullPointerException`s in general, whereas this question is really about Android lifecycle events. I've voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess: You have two different layouts -- one for portrait and one for landscape. Only one of those will be loaded through `findViewById`, depending on the device orientation. Remember that the activity is recreated (and `onCreate` called) when you rotate the device. You should just check `listPort` and `listLand` for `null` before setting the adapter. You're not using both at the same time.

Something like this:

```
if (listPort != null) {
    listPort.setAdapter(customAdapter); // Portrait mode
} else {
    listLand.setAdapter(customAdapter); // Landscape mode
}
```

One of them should be non-null, provided everything else works as it should.

If, as I'm guessing, you have one `values/activity_main.xml` and one `values-land/activity_main.xml`, you could make life easier for yourself by using the same list id both places. E.g.,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Flick> flicks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        flicks = new ArrayList<>();
        flicks.add(new Flick("Wizard of Oz", "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer", "VARIOUS","1939", "", 98));
        ...
        flicks.add(new Flick("Jaws", "Universal", "Steven Spielberg", "1975", "", 97));

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_layout, flicks);
        listt.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
    ...
}
```